# How can I send data by API and then redirect to the page

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, redirect

I have a form and I should send data to the server by API, but then I want to redirect to the page that I want. Because I use Vue-router, I want to use :to="", it redirects, but doesn't send data.

```
<form :action="`/my/api/`" method="post">
  <input name="file" v-model="form.file" type="file" />
  <input name="name" v-model="form.name" label="Name"/>

  <btn label="send" type="submit" v-close-popup/>
</form>
```

How this issue could be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the requirement, You have to follow these steps **:**

- Instead of directly perform `action` in the form, You should invoke a method on submit which will responsible to make an API call with the form data.
- On success response from an API, You can redirect the user to the specific route.

Template code should be **:**

```
<form>
  <input name="file" v-model="form.file" type="file" />
  <input name="name" type="text" v-model="form.name" label="Name"/>

  <button @click="sendFormData">Send</button>
</form>
```

In script **:**

```
data: {
  form: {
    file: '',
    name: ''
  }
},
methods: {
  sendFormData() {
    // Creating a payload using form fields `v-model`
    const payload = this.form;
    // API call
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    })
    .then(() => {
      this.$router.push('<your route>')
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this programmatically by putting all the actions you want to execute on submit into a single method and have the form call that method on submit. The below code includes some simplifications and is not the exact code necessary to complete your task. It is just meant to provide a general idea of what to do.

```html
<form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
  <input />
  <input />
  ...
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    submitForm() {
      // prepare/validate all form data to be submitted
      const formData = { ... }
      // submit form data
      fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
      })
      .then(() => {
        // go to new page
        this.$router.push('/someRoute')
      })
      .catch(() => {
        // handle error
      })
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Could you explain what is {...}?

Comment: it's placeholder code meant to represent the object you want to send to your API containing all your input values.  I don't know what your API expects, maybe it can just be equal to `form` or maybe you need to format it in some different way.  Whatever data needs to be sent by your fetch call, that's what `formData` is.